# using styled-component in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am first time using styled-component with react.js. My code is in Abc.js and in styles.js I have styled-component code.

```
 export const StyledPopopDiv = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #cecece;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  left: ${state => state.pos.x}px;
  top: {state.pos.y}px;
`;
StyledPopopDiv.displayName = 'StyledPopopDiv';
```

I am trying to pass state.pos.x in styled-component, but this is giving error `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`.

I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: check this @raju https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k186te , hope this help and explore how you used(import) StyledPopopDiv .

Answer (score 1):

You should first of all pass the state as a prop to the styled component example :

```
// Abc.js

<StyledPopopDiv pos={posState} />
```

So you can use this prop on your styled component definition as below:

```
//styled.js 

 export const StyledPopopDiv = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #cecece;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  left: ${ props => props.pos.x}px;  // outputs '10px' in this example
  top: ${ props => props.pos.y}px;  // outputs '20px' in this example
`;
```

A better way/tip is to use destruction/spread operator example :

```
 export const StyledPopopDiv = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #cecece;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  left: ${ ({ pos }) => pos.x}px; 
  top: ${ ({ pos }) => pos.y}px;
`;
```

Comment: Good solution, but I think the space between the closing `}` and the `px` will result in some errors, given we the generated css will be `left: 10 px` for x=10

Comment: Also, you should consider use [`withConfig` defining `shouldForwardProp`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop) in styled components. By default, it will try to pass `x`and `y` to the `div` component, which doesn't expect to receive these props, causing a console warning.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `props` instead of state, assuming you're using StyledPopupDiv in Abc.js render.

Comment: pos{x:10,y:20} (e.g.) are in component state and changing based upon user click on document. these are not passed by parent component

Comment: Well, they should be passed as props, that's how styled-components work: it creates components with styles attached to them. Your StyledPopupDiv is just another component. Judging by how you named your files 'Abc' and 'styles' I have to ask - have you read through documentation: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics ? It's well written and explains motivations behind the library.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface StyledPopupDivProps{
x:string
}

export const StyledPopopDiv =
styled<LinkProps, "div">("div")`
margin: ${props=>props.x}
`;
```

and pass

```
<StyledPopupDiv x={intendedValue}/>
```

where its being used.